# Is there a Magic Method for type() in python?

Tags: python, magic-methods

I was wondering if there was a magic method in Python that supported the type() built-in function, that would allow you to set a custom value to be returned.

Comment: And what would that achieve? What problem do you think you can solve with this?

Comment: The short answer is: no, there is no such method. You can switch the type on an instance (just assign a different class object to `instance.__class__` but that means behaviour changes as well.

Comment: I was purely academically interested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no such method. An instance's type is not something you can dynamically alter when querying for it, as that would be type-specific behaviour, but you suddenly cannot determine the type that is defining that behaviour!

You *can* assign a different class to `instance.__class__`, but then you'd materially alter the behaviour of that instance, and it is not the instance itself that then changes type when `type()` is applied to the instance.

Rather than using `type()`, use the `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` functions instead, and use abstract base types; it is the *type object* that is then responsible for claiming a specific class or instance as a subclass or instance of the given type, respectively. They can do this via the [`__issubclass__` and `__isinstance__` hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks).